# Why does my image keep flashing in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, pycharm, chess

The code for my image in pygame:

```py
img = pg.image.load(position[0][1].image).convert_alpha()
img = pg.transform.scale(img, (100, 100))
pg.display.update()
window.blit(img, (100, 0))
pg.display.update()
```

image:
[black knight png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4YRu.png)

For some reason my knight keeps flashing and doesn't work properly with my background, can someone help fix this. The PNG doesn't work for some reason.(it's not transparent with the background)

The pieces aren't loading with the board, the red squares keeps "clashing" with the pieces. [chess board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvZhT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is flashing because of the multiple calls to `pg.display.update()`. Call `pg.display.update()` only once at the end of the application loop:

```py
img = pg.image.load(position[0][1].image).convert_alpha()
img = pg.transform.scale(img, (100, 100))

while True:
    # [...]

    window.blit(img, (100, 0))
    pg.display.update()
```